# How does sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict work?

Tags: cross-validation, prediction, scikit-learn

What exactly does `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict` do and how does it work?

Documentation says:

"Generate cross-validated estimates for each input data point

The data is split according to the cv parameter. Each sample belongs to exactly one test set, and its prediction is computed with an estimator fitted on the corresponding training set."

Does it break the input data into folds, put them into a previously fitted model, and (in the case of classification) majority vote the 0 or 1 output?

That seems suspect and I don't think I have it right.  That would mean it would need to make 10 predictions for each observation and then (maybe) majority vote the final classification?

Also, is the cv in the prediction separate and distinct in cv used to fit the model with which I'm making predictions?

What is the advantage of using `sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict` over `predict`?

Confused.

Thanks in advance for any clarity.

Comment: similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458834/how-is-scikit-learn-cross-val-predict-accuracy-score-calculated

Answer (score 0):

The function `cross_val_predict` has a similar interface to `cross_val_score`, but returns, for each element in the input, the prediction that was obtained for that element when it was in the test set. Only cross-validation strategies that assign all elements to a test set exactly once can be used (otherwise, an exception is raised).

Example

```
    x : a, b, c, d, e   
    y : p, q, r, s, t
```

Predicting y when x is a. Model cross val predict will use is one in which 'a' was test data and b,c,d,e were in train data. And for x = b, it will take a model in which b is in test data and a,c,d,e are used in the training model.
Those will be your values of `y_predict`.